# How may I reset my Villager's house back to its normal furnishings in Animal Crossing New Horizon?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have a villager named Julian on my island with costly and beautiful tastes. His home is furnished with zodiac star themed furniture. Before I understood that if you give your villagers pieces of furniture, they can place the furniture in their homes and replace something existing that they own. I regret giving Julian a piece of furniture that does not match his decor. Is there a way I can reset his house, so all of the original furniture is in its original place? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A week ago, I was gifted a few Nintendo Animal Crossing Happy Home Designer Amiibo Cards, including villagers Lily and Julian. I invited Lily to come to my campsite via the ABD (ATM Machine) inside the Resident Services building under the invite a camper via amiibo option. I proceeded to visit the campsite and speak with Lily, which she requested a souvenir from my island. She asked for a (DIY) Log Chair), and when I gave her the Log Chair, she hinted that I should invite her back the following day. My goal was to invite her to replace the current Julian on my island, and with my Julian Amiibo card, I would invite him to replace another villager on my island. I was successful in resetting Julian's home after 3 days of requesting Lily to my campsite giving her a souvenir each day which the game then gave me an option of the specific villager I would like Lily to replace. I then repeated the same steps to invite Julian back to my island and voila his house is now back to its original state. My friend also wanted Julian on her island so when my original Julian was packing his boxes, she visited my island and was able to invite Julian to stay on her island. To be very specific this new Julian that now resides at my island is not my original Julian. That Julian, who currently resides at my friend's island, still remembers me when I visit her island. His house is also pristine with beautiful furniture.